# Binding Tooltip to Content Presenter Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

I am styling a TreeViewItem. The item has a content presenter that I wish to have a tooltip appear:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
             Cursor="Hand"
             Grid.Column="1"
             ContentSource="Header"
             HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
   <ContentPresenter.ToolTip>
       <ToolTip 
                 Placement="RelativePoint" 
                 VerticalOffset="-2" 
                 HasDropShadow="False"
                 BorderBrush="#767676" 
                 Background="#FFF" 
                 Padding="0,1,0,1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                 AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=Content}"/>
   </ContentPresenter.ToolTip>
</ContentPresenter>
```

This is effectively part of a larger setter that sets the item's control template. However, I cannot seem to get the Tooltip's content binded to the content presenter's content. It keeps appearing blank (a tiny black box). I am new to binding and WPF, so please excuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ToolTips and other popups exist outside the main visual tree and so can't use RelativeSource to get to parents. Try instead using the ToolTip's PlacementTarget property to get to its parent ContentPresenter:

```
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Content}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue was frustrating me for several hours.

Comment: This binding has created a bug: If I have a TreeView item image, the binding seems to remove the content of the treeviewitem when the tooltip finishes displaying. Would you know any fixes?

Comment: Try putting an Image in your ToolTip and binding the Source properties together instead of the Content itself. When the Content is a UI element instead of text or data it could be pulling in the Image control itself, which can't have 2 parents and so is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I want use Binding like if my tooltip or popup is child of control which creates them.
In previous answer i can't do it.
I write example for custom tooltip, but you can do it for popup, use behavior or another - it is easy.
My custom ToolTip:

```
public class ToolTipEx : ToolTip
{
    private readonly FrameworkElement _coreParent;

    static ToolTipEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ToolTipEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToolTipEx)));
    }

    public ToolTipEx(FrameworkElement parent)
    {
        _coreParent = parent;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var method = typeof(FrameworkElement).GetMethod("AddLogicalChild", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        method.Invoke(_coreParent, new object[] { Parent });
    }
}
```

After it you can use correct bindings:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ToolTipEx}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Border Background="Black"
                        CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyControl}}, Path=MyProperty}"
                               Margin="1"
                               Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                               TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you would just add the binding to the tooltip property itself?

```
<ContentPresenter ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}">
```